# Invite Channel Notification Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So i am coding a bot , in Node.js with Visual Studio Code. I want to have a channel, that when a user joins the guild , will send 'Welcome user and invited by thisuser(Total Invites: 5)

The code is :

```
module.exports = (client) => {
  const invites = {} // { guildId: { memberId: count } }

  const getInviteCounts = async (guild) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => {
      guild.fetchInvites().then((invites) => {
        const inviteCounter = {} // { memberId: count }

        invites.forEach((invite) => {
          const { uses, inviter } = invite
          const { username, discriminator } = inviter

          const name = `${username}#${discriminator}`

          inviteCounter[name] = (inviteCounter[name] || 0) + uses
        })

        resolve(inviteCounter)
      })
    })
  }

  client.guilds.cache.forEach(async (guild) => {
    invites[guild.id] = await getInviteCounts(guild)
  })

  client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
    const { guild, id } = member

    const invitesBefore = invites[guild.id]
    const invitesAfter = await getInviteCounts(guild)

    console.log('BEFORE:', invitesBefore)
    console.log('AFTER:', invitesAfter)

    for (const inviter in invitesAfter) {
      if (invitesBefore[inviter] === invitesAfter[inviter] - 1) {
        const channelId = '731801004462571602'
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        const count = invitesAfter[inviter]
        channel.send(
          `Please welcome <@${id}> to the Discord! Invited by ${inviter} (${count} invites)`
        )

        invites[guild.id] = invitesAfter
        return
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This code works perfectly with console but i am facing a problem,never post the message in the channel!

Answer (score 1):

The message might not be being sent because of the channel ID double check you are using the right channel ID and you might want to try changing
`const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)` to this
`const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId)`

Comment: Give this one a shot, I have used this in my application and it seems to work. 
```Client.channels.cache.get('ChannelID').send("Message!")```

Comment: i did that and its the same!